# С# Bank Class and method for calculation of the total amount of deposits

Tags: c#, class, oop

I have the Bank Class and there are three owners and their balance.
 So i need to write a method for calculation of the total amount of deposits but i don't know how. Could i have some help? And this method should be in interface

```
public interface IAccount
{
    decimal GetBalance();

}
public class Account : IAccount
{
    private string owner;
    private decimal balance;

    public Account(string owner, decimal balance)
    {
        this.owner = owner;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public string Getowner()
    {
        return owner;
    }
    public decimal GetBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Owner: {0},Balance: {1}", owner, balance);
    }

}
public class Bank
{
    List<Account> BankList = new List<Account>();
    public void AddAccount(params Account[] acc)
    {
        BankList.AddRange(acc);
        for (int i = 0; i < acc.Length; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("Have added: {0}", acc[i].ToString());
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string str = "\nBalance in bank:\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < BankList.Count; i++)
            str += String.Format(BankList[i].ToString() + "\n");
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide and edit your question accordingly or create a new one

Comment: The account class has information about only owner and balance. Where is the code of deposit? What functionality related to deposit you want to implement?

Comment: Take a look [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You are missing this: *Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"So i need to write a method for calculation of the total amount of deposits"*

```
public decimal GetTotalAmount()
{
    return BankList.Sum(x => x.GetBalance());
}
```

*"And this method should be in interface"*

```
public interface IBank
{
    decimal GetTotalAmount();
}
```

Then implement the interface...

```
public class Bank : IBank
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the deposits into a list variable and then loop through the list, adding each deposit to a currentBalance variable.

You can put this where you want to store the deposits like your bank class

```
List<decimal> deposits = new List<decimal>():
```

Then call your GetBalance method and pass it your list:

```
GetBalance (List<decimal> balances) 
{
     decimal currentBalance = 0;

     foreach (var balance in balances)
     {
           currentBalance += balance;
     }

      return currentBalance;
}
```

So that way you can add up all the deposits and find your balance, and if you need to do that for all the accounts you can do a loop of the accounts list in a similar fashion with variables declared outside the loop.